# How to remove a single letter/number

Tags: tcl, eggdrop

I have single letters and numbers in a variable that I would like to remove

example inputs:

```
USA-2019-1-aoiwer
USA-A-jowerasf
BB-a_owierlasdf-2019
flsfwer_5_2015-asfdlwer
```

desired outputs:

```
USA-2019--aoiwer
USA--jowerasf
BB-_owierlasdf-2019
flsfwer__2015-asfdlwer
```

my code:

```
bind pub "-|-" !aa proc:aa
proc proc:aa { nick host handle channel arg } {

    set line [lindex $arg 0]

    set line [string map {[a-z] """} $line]
    set line [string map {[0-9] """} $line]


    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :$line"
}
```

Unfortunately that does not work and i have no other idea

Regards

Comment: Do you have some error message?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you want it to perform. How do you decide that in the first example, `1` should be removed, in the second, `A` should be removed, in the third, `a` should be removed and in the last, `5` should be removed?

Comment: Jerry, t is always the single characters or numbers, only with length 1, regards

Comment: See the regsub command. You will need to work out a regular expression that matches your desired data fields. For instance "[\_-][:alphanum:][\_-]" would match a single alphanumeric char with either underscore or hyphen on either side.

Comment: set line [regsub -all "[_-][:alphanum:][_-]" "" $line]    error: invalid command name "_-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string map` would remove all the lowercase letters and numbers, if it worked. However, you also have unbalanced quotes, which causes a syntax error when the proc is resolving.

I would recommend using `regsub`. The hard part, however, would be to get a proper expression to do the task. I will suggest the following:

```
bind pub "-|-" !aa proc:aa

proc proc:aa { nick host handle channel arg } {
    set line [lindex $arg 0]
    regsub -nocase -all {([^a-z0-9]|\y)[a-z0-9]([^a-z0-9]|\y)} $line {\1\2} line
    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :$line"
}
```

Basically `([^a-z0-9]|\y)` matches a character that is non alphanumeric, or a word boundary (which will match at the beginning of a sentence for example if it can, or at the end of a sentence), and stores it (this is the purpose of the parens).

The matched groups are stored in order starting with 1, so in the replace portion of `regsub`, I'm placing the parts that shouldn't be replaced back where they were.

The above should work fine.

---

You could technically go a little fancier with a slightly different expression:

```
regsub -nocase -all {([^a-z0-9]|\y)[a-z0-9](?![a-z0-9])} $line {\1} line
```

Which uses a negative lookahead (`(?! ... )`).

Anyway, if you do want to get more in depth, I recommend reading the [manual](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) on regular expression syntax